# Chart error en reporte de Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6

Estimada/e/o/s, tengan buenas tardes, he venido a ustedes nuevamente a consultarles lo siguiente. Tengo un programa realizado en `VB6` el cual debe mostrar un reporte con **gráficos**.
Pero, a la hora de querer mostrarlo (luego de instalado el ejecutable de la aplicación en distintas computadoras) obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Chart library "SSCSDK80.DLL" cannot be found. It should be on the path.
```

Al presionar el botón de **"aceptar"** (cuando se muestra el error) puedo visualizar el reporte **pero sin los gráficos**. En todas las máquinas donde no he instalado el `Crystal Report`, he obtenido ese error. Lo ideal sería no tener que instalar el CR en cada computadora para poder visualizar los gráficos. He copiado la `DLL` respectivamente en las ubicaciones `System32/SysWOW64` (En esta ubicación ya existía esta `DLL`) pero al querer registrarlas sucede lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto como en `System32` como en `SysWOW64` el error es el mismo a la hora de querer registrarlas. Mi consulta es si alguien ha podido solucionar este inconveniente sin tener que instalar el `CR` en computadoras para que se puedan visualizar los gráficos.

Comment: Lo ideal sería crear un API rest que se encargue de crear y servir los reportes a las aplicaciones y así se olvida de tener que andar instalando y/ó registrando DLLs por todas partes y solo tendría que hacerlo en un solo servidor.

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué versión de CR estás utilizando? ¿Incluiste el `.dll` en tu ejecutable?

Comment: Estoy utilizando la versión 10 del CR @HeytalePazguato la dll no la incluí en mi ejecutable, todavía no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

En la [documentación](http://www.threedgraphics.com/tdg/products/tools/crchart/html_docs/docs/gettingstarted.htm) se menciona:

> Deploying Your CRChart Solution:
> For developers who are preparing
> applications for distribution that use CRChart macros, the charting
> library (SSCSDK80.DLL) file must be shipped with your application.

Es decir, debes incluir el archivo `SSCSDK80.DLL` en el ejecutable.

En las propiedades del `dll` configura `Build Action` como `Content` y `Copy to Output Directory` como `Copy if newer` para que en caso de que el `dll` ya exista y el del ejecutable sea más nuevo pueda ser reemplazado.

En la misma página se menciona la forma de configurarlo en un servidor por si prefieres hacerlo de esa forma.